# Writing/ Appending data to Plist returns nill

Tags: ios, ios8, plist

I am writing data to plist with always returns me the nil value.. I have to append data also to the previous values of array. But Values are always null..
Below is the code:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// get documents path
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// get the path to our Data/plist file
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"a.plist"];

// set the variables to the values in the text fields


// create dictionary with values in UITextFields
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"c" forKey:@"Id"];


if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
{
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    [array addObject:plistDict];

    [array writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"array%@",array);
}
else
{
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:plistPath];
    [array writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: Is your array always nil, even for first time? Or where does it returns nil in `if` block or `else` block?

Comment: alwys returm in IF condition

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I tested the code with just one little change i.e, Added array declaration and it's working fine. Please pardon me if this is not the issue.

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // get documents path
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    // get the path to our Data/plist file
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"a.plist"];

    // set the variables to the values in the text fields
    NSMutableArray *array;

    // create dictionary with values in UITextFields
    NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"c" forKey:@"Id"];


    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
    {
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
        [array addObject:plistDict];

        [array writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];


        NSLog(@"array%@",array);

    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:plistPath];
        [array writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Does it make difference...array declaration in method... or defining globally in .h